# How to pass array of images in opencv to a function?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am able to pass single images to a function using openCv c++`enter code here` but not able to pass array of image.
eg:The below function I am able to pass

```
function correct(Mat & img)
   {
   }

   correct(img);
```

The below example is not working for array of images.
I img[20] is a array;

```
 function correct(Mat &img[i])
   {
   }

   corrcet(img[i]);
```

Comment: use `std::vector<cv::Mat>` instead :)

Comment: I need to store images in array using Mat , these images I need for deflickering. For eg: for 5th frame , I need frames of 4th , 3rd,2nd,1st frame . i used Mat img[50] . stored all the frames in img[5], when i am using img[3], img[2],img[1] , I am getting the present frame stored in it . I am not able to access as an array in c/c++ , ie when you take and address , the element in that address is chosed. Please help

Comment: I would recommend you to use `std::vector` over `array` as `vector` handles a lot of complexities by itself

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code, but I think it's better to use vectors.

```
void correct(cv::Mat img[]){
   ...
}
```